# Help with apache to nginx rewrite rules

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, rewrite

I need help converting some Apache .htaccess rules to nginx ones. Hope someone around more experienced could help me. Here are my rules:

1

```
    RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.url.ba [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://url.ba/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^api\.php /index.php?c=api&m=index&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^contact\.php /index.php?c=contact&m=index&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,25})$ /index.php?c=api&m=check&hash=$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|script|ZeroClipboard\.swf)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+) / [R=301,L]
```

2

```
    RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.img.ba.ba$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://img.ba/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond $1 !(\/protected)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/protected$ /protected.php?hash=$1 [L]


RewriteCond $1 !(thumb\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/thumb$ /thumb.php?hash=$1 [L]


RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|thumb\.php|upload\.php|contact\.php|protected\.php|api\.php|password\.php|favicon\.ico|images|css|script)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?hash=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+) / [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the rules ready, it's easy. Here are the guidelines

- Read the rewrite [docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)
- Read the core [variables](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables) (`%{HTTP_HOST}` becomes `$host`, for example)
- `RewriteCond` will be turned into `if` [blocks](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#if)
- `RewriteRules` are pretty much the same, except the variable differences and the usage of regular expressions. Also, flags are written in full like `break`, `permanent` and so on.

There are many examples on the rewrite page.

Answer (score 0):

Most apache rewrite conditions should *not* be turned into if blocks.  Those conditions matching HTTP_HOST should be turned into server blocks, those matching the uri or request filename should be replaced with location blocks, and those testing existence of files should be replaced with try_files.  Please don't use if blocks where they're not necessary.  Assuming that all dynamic requests are supposed to go through php, I think the correct translation of those rules is:

```
server {
  server_name www.url.ba;
  rewrite ^ http://url.ba$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  server_name url.ba;

  root /path/to/root;

  location = /api.php { rewrite ^ /index.php?c=api&m=index; }
  location = /contact.php { rewrite ^ /index.php?c=contact&m=index; }

  location ~ "/([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,25})$" /index.php?c=api&m=check&hash=$1?; }

  location /index.php {
    fastcgi_split_path_info (/index.php)(.*);
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_pass your_backend;
  }

  location /images { try_files $uri @home; }
  location /css { try_files $uri @home; }
  location /script { try_files $uri @home; }
  location /ZeroClipboard.swf { try_files $uri @home; }
  location @home { rewrite ^ / permanent; }

  location / {
    rewrite ^ /index.php$uri;
  }
}

server {
  # Did you really mean .ba.ba?
  server_name www.img.ba.ba;
  rewrite ^ http://img.ba$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  server_name img.ba;

  # I'm not positive that these translations are correct,
  # I'm guessing that the repeated $1 is always the requested
  # uri in the apache rules

  # The (?<variable> capture syntax is 0.8.25+.  If you're
  # running an older version, the easiest way will be to
  # repeat the location regex in the rewrite and capture $1

  location ~ ^/(?<hash>.*)/protected$ {
    rewrite ^ /protected.php?hash=$hash;
  }

  location ~ ^/(?<hash>.*)/thumb\.php$ {
    rewrite ^ /thumb.php?hash=$hash;
  }

  location ~ ~/(index|thumb|upload|contact|protected|api|password)\.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_pass your_backend;
  }

  location /images { try_files $uri @home; }
  location /css { try_files $uri @home; }
  location /script { try_files $uri @home; }
  location @home { rewrite ^ / permanent; }

  location / { rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?hash=$1; }
}
```